# Is it possible to change the classic ASP response once you've written to it?

Tags: asp-classic, response, response.write

If I have a classic ASP response in the format:

```
someJsFunctionName({"0":{"field1":0,"field2":"","field3":0,"field4":2,"field5":1,"field6":1}});
```

that is built with

```
response.write "someFunctionName(" 
someMethod(param1, param2).Flush
response.write ");"
```

If I want to insert a new field to the response

```
someJsFunctionName({"0":{"field1":0,"field2":"","field3":0,"field4":2,"field5":1,"field6":1, "field7":2}});
```

Would I be able to call a method similar to

```
response.replace("}});", "\"field7\":2}});")
```

?
Or would I have to clear the entire response to write a new string into it?
Would I have to keep track of the result of `someMethod(param1, param2).Flush`, modify that string before writing it to the response?

Comment: Build it as a string variable then pass it to `Call Response.Write(myfuncstring)`. To be clear there is no way to manipulate the Response buffer other then `Call Response.Clear()` and start again before `Call Response.Flush()` after that there is no going back as the headers are already written.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart, add this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any need for you to output directly to the `Response` buffer, to be clear you can only manipulate the `Response` buffer up to the point you `Call Response.Flush()` as this clears the buffer and writes the headers. Up to that point you can still `Call Response.Clear()` to empty the buffer without writing it then fill the buffer again with `Call Response.Write("yourstring")`.

The reason I can't see a need for this is because you could get the same effect by simply assigning your string to a variable building it up (manipulating it with `Replace()` if you want to) then `Call Response.Write(yourstringvariable)` to output it.

```vb
Dim myfunc

myfunc = "someFunctionName("
'someMethod should return a string
myfunc = myfunc & someMethod(param1, param2)
myfunc = myfunc & ");"

Call Response.Write(myfunc)
```